# Convolution in Golang

Tags: image-processing, go, convolution

I want execute a convolution product on an image.

The original image is:

[image]

So I test the convolution with gimp. With this matrix:

1 1 1

1 1 1

1 1 1

and the divider 9

I obtain

[image]

When I execute my algorithm I obtain:

[image]

My algorithm is:

```
func Convolution(img *image.Image, matrice [][]int) *image.NRGBA {
    imageRGBA := image.NewNRGBA((*img).Bounds())
    w := (*img).Bounds().Dx()
    h := (*img).Bounds().Dy()
    sumR := 0
    sumB := 0
    sumG := 0
    var r uint32
    var g uint32
    var b uint32
    for y := 0; y < h; y++ {
        for x := 0; x < w; x++ {

            for i := -1; i <= 1; i++ {
                for j := -1; j <= 1; j++ {

                    var imageX int
                    var imageY int

                    imageX = x + i
                    imageY = y + j

                    r, g, b, _ = (*img).At(imageX, imageY).RGBA()
                    sumG = (sumG + (int(g) * matrice[i+1][j+1]))
                    sumR = (sumR + (int(r) * matrice[i+1][j+1]))
                    sumB = (sumB + (int(b) * matrice[i+1][j+1]))
                }
            }

            imageRGBA.Set(x, y, color.NRGBA{
                uint8(min(sumR/9, 255)),
                uint8(min(sumG/9, 255)),
                uint8(min(sumB/9, 255)),
                255,
            })

            sumR = 0
            sumB = 0
            sumG = 0

        }
    }

    return imageRGBA

}
```

Where are the error ? 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r`, `g`, and `b` are `uint32` values, and they contain 16bits of color information which is always greater than 255 if started as a non-zero 8 bit value.

You then can't operate on the RGBA values and truncate them to a `uint8`; that gives you a useless result because the least significant bits are just fractional parts of the 8bit values.

Compare the candidate integer value with the max 16bit value 65535, and shift it 8 bits before truncating it to get the 8 most significant bits.

```
uint8(min(sumR/9, 0xffff) >> 8),
uint8(min(sumG/9, 0xffff) >> 8),
uint8(min(sumB/9, 0xffff) >> 8),
```